# How actual data is stored in B-Tree in case of index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, b-tree

I know SQL Server uses a B-Tree when we create an index on a column. I know the leaf nodes have the actual data in case of the clustered index, and leaf nodes have the pointer to actual data in case of non-clustered index. I know when we create index on a column other than `Int` data type, SQL Server creates an additional column of 4-byte. But I am still confused about the following questions:

1. How the actual B-Tree will look if we have clustered index on `int` data type column and on non-int data type column?
2. How B-Tree will look if the clustered index is composite key?
3. How the actual B-tree will look in case of non-clustered index?

I will be thankful if anyone refer some link where i can look B-Tree with sample column data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I know when we create index on the column other than Int data type SQL Server creates the additional column of 4-byte" - I suspect this is a garbled reference to the [uniquifier](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2082/understanding-and-examining-the-uniquifier-in-sql-server/) which relates to *clustering a non-unique index* rather than anything about indexes on `int` columns specifically.

Comment: I read somewhere that sql server created extra 4 byte column if datatype in not int or unique in case of clustered index

Comment: SQL Server will create this 4-byte **uniquefier** only if you create a **non-unique** clustered index - no matter what the datatype...... the clustered index **must be** unique - if you don't make sure it is, SQL Server will do so for you.

Comment: And the nonclustered leaf nodes do not contain a "pointer" to the data - what they contain is the **clustering column(s)** of that table (assuming it's clustered). Once an entry is found in the non-clustered index, a search over the clustered index can be made to find the complete data for an entry

Comment: @marc_s thanks for you reply. I meant that it has a pointer to clustered index column or heap in case of no clustered index on the table.

Comment: Have a look at the MCM readiness videos about index internals,  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn912438#mcm-readiness

Comment: @Umer: again, it doesn't have a **pointer** to something - it has the **actual** columns that make up the **clustered index** in the nonclustered leaf nodes.

Comment: @marc_s what if there is no clustered index in the table?

Comment: Then you'd have a "RID" (row identifier) - and this *could be* considered a pointer - but you really should never actually have a table without a clustering key, in SQL Server ...

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.